# In Reportlab what data format for Table

Tags: django, python-2.7, reportlab, pypdf

IN report i try to add row and column but face error

> TypeError at /billing/invioce_report/ 'int' object is not iterable

```
    product_data = [
                str(bill.creation_date), bill.bill_number, bill.staff.user.first_name + " " + bill.staff.user.last_name,
                 products_in_bill.product_qty,
                 str(products_in_bill), products_in_bill.product.reference_number, products_in_bill.product.cost,
                 products_in_bill.discounted_price, products_in_bill.product.cost,
                 customer_name,
                 name,
                 comm_amount,
                 payment_type
                 ]
            print 123
            tp = Table(product_data, 13 * [1.25 * inch], len(product_data) * [0.25 * inch])
            tp.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (1, 1), (-2, -2), 'RIGHT'),
                                   ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), 'TOP'),
                                   ('ALIGN', (0, -1), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                                   ('VALIGN', (0, -1), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
                                   ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
                                   ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
                                   ]))

            pdf_data.append(tp)
            all_data.append(tp)
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that the `reportlab.platypus.Table` object's data argument needs to be a list of lists, not a simple list. This nested list is a 2-dimensional grid of data, i.e. the same structure as a table. This is described in the [open source docs](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), chapter 7.1 on Table methods.

```
# So this will work:
data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
]

# as will a single row:
data = [ [1,2,3] ]

# but a simple list with numbers in it will not work (your current data):
data = [1,2,3]

# however, a list of strings appears to work - like table headings?
data = ['testing', '1', '2']
```

Comment: yeah this true. what is solution for this?

Comment: try an extra pair of brackets around product_data: `product_data = [[ ... ]]`. Or, I see you said you wanted rows and columns in your message, so if you want more than one row then order your data like a grid.

Comment: I try to add pair of brackets. but still face error. like i mention in question

Comment: Look at product_data vs. pdf_data.

Comment: Kindly write here some code so i can easily understand

Comment: You can do it. This site is not intended for case-by-case debugging. Look at my answer and comments and look at your code again - the solution is there. Rubber duck debugging will solve your problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: (Hope you managed to get it working. In the code sample you pasted, there was still only one pair of brackets around `product_data`.)